# Losing newlines in div content in IE 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, split, newline, innerhtml

I'm trying to split the innerText of a div on the newlines in the source for it.  This works fine with:

```
$('div').text().split("\r\n|\r|\n")
```

But this fails in IE 7, due to the newlines apparently being stripped out.  jQuery 1.3.2 doesn't appear to be at fault since i also tried both:

```
$('div')[0].innerText.split("\r\n|\r|\n")
```

and

```
$('div')[0].innerHTML.split("\r\n|\r|\n")
```

Neither do any of the above work if i change the div to a pre.

It appears that the newlines are once the source is parsed into the DOM. :(  Is this so?  Is there no way to get at them with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines are whitespace, and are not generally preserved. They mean the same thing as a space does.

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting on `"\n"` instead of `"\r\n"`.

To do both, consider splitting on the pattern `"\r?\n"`.

Comment: I've tried on \n, \r, \r\n|\r|\n, and other things that should work.  It's not the regex, i'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

IE does lose newlines in element content, except:

- in `pre` (and `plaintext`, not that that's ever used this century)
- in `textarea`, where it also adds spurious ‘\r’s that don't count towards its own character-counting mechanisms

However, regardless of that, this won't work:

> split("\r\n|\r|\n")

JavaScript's String.split, in contrast to Java's, takes a simple delimiter string, *not* a regex pattern.